# React native set value depending on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to set value to state depending on checkbox selection, like if the 'Screening and Diagnosis' checkbox is true, set the state of screening to the 'ScreeningAndDiagnosis' string value.

How can I achieve something like that ?

I'm stuck at this level of code

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)', padding: 15}}>
      <CheckBox onValueChange={ (value) => this.setState({ screening.checked : !this.state.screening.checked }) } value={ this.state.screening.checked } />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize : 16, fontWeight: '500'}}> Screening And Diagnosis </Text>
    </View>
```

and I have the state like this

```
this.state = {
  screening : { checked : false, value : '' },
}
```

Comment: For this you have to assign the properties to the object. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117724/react-native-setstate-on-object-inside-state

Comment: Hi Haboosh. I am a volunteer editor here, and one of the things I do is to try to encourage post authors to write their material in such a way that does not need repair. Unfortunately, we do not have enough editors to cope with the workload as it is, in order to make questions and answers as readable as possible for future developers.

Comment: With that in mind, please (1) observe the usual case rules for English, so "I" (myself) is a capital; (2) sentences in a single paragraph are allowed to wrap naturally, and do not need intermediate line breaks, (3) chatty material, thanks and appreciations are omitted, since these are not appropriate for technical writing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this I am using native-base checkbox and note that the value for the checkbox can only be maintained in the state and not in the component and so you have to bind the component with the state and change the checked prop based on the state. It means that you have the value in the state and the checkbox UI is used to show you the state the value is

```
    export default class CheckBox extends Component{
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          checked:false;
        }
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)', padding: 15}}>
            <CheckBox checked={this.state.checked} onPress={()=>this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked})}/>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize : 16, fontWeight: '500'}}> Screening And Diagnosis </Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```